# Looping over parent data (set via Ajax) in child components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I loop over data set via ajax in my component methods? The problem is that when I try to call a method to perform the loop on component mounted(), the data isn't there yet. How can I tell my vue component to wait for the ajax data to arrive to execute the function?

```js
Vue.component('sidebar', {
  props: ['people'],
  template: `
        <div id="sidebarContain" v-if="this.people">
            <div v-for="person in people" :class="[{'checked-in': isCheckedIn(person)}, 'person']" :id="person.id">
                {{person.first_name + ' ' + person.last_name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
  methods: {
    isCheckedIn(person) {
      return person.reg_scan == null ? true : false;
    },
    displayName() { //this is the function I want to run when ajax data is done and passed from parent to child
      for (var i = 0; i < this.people.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.people[i]);
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.displayName();
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
    people: []
  },
  methods: {
    loadPeople() {
      $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: base_url + 'users/getParticipants/' + event_id
      }).done(data => {
        this.people = data;
      });
    },
    setRefresh() {
      setInterval(() => {
        console.log("Getting People");
        this.loadPeople();
      }, 10000);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadPeople();
    this.setRefresh();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <sidebar :people="people"></sidebar>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a watcher on the people array and call the displayName function on the watcher. Whenever the data in the people array changes the watcher is run, so it will be run when the ajax request returns the data from the API. Another option would be to run the loop immediately on the callback.